# Using VB.Net in ASP.Net MVC EF6 Database First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

I am a complete Noob with EF and am trying to create my first application using it but i'm falling at the first hurdle as i'm trying to learn it using VB.NET instead of C# meaning there is absolutely no resources out there. Issue i'm having is that when i attempt to generate the model in VB, it doesn't actually populate like its supposed to. i.e. show all the files created under the edmx folder. I have tried the same thing with c# and it works fine as in i can see all the .cs and .tt files that have been generated. So can someone tell me where im going wrong? the reason i'm doing this in VB rather than c# is simply because im more comfortable with vb syntax.

Comment: I will try to post some example code today for you.  I would suggest switching to c#  I used to code in vb but i forced myself to switch and enjoy c# better.

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually mastering c# is in my 10 year plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have pasted some code below.  What else are you looking for?  I prefer the Fluent API approach.  I like to use this tool:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

Here is the code in C#

```
public partial class Grade
{
    public Grade()
    {
        this.Students = new List<Student>();
        this.Teachers = new List<Teacher>();
    }

    public int GradeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code in VB

```
Public Partial Class Grade
Public Sub New()
    Me.Students = New List(Of Student)()
    Me.Teachers = New List(Of Teacher)()
End Sub

Public Property GradeID() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_GradeID
    End Get
    Set
        m_GradeID = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_GradeID As Integer
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return m_Name
    End Get
    Set
        m_Name = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Name As String
Public Overridable Property Students() As ICollection(Of Student)
    Get
        Return m_Students
    End Get
    Set
        m_Students = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private Overridable m_Students As ICollection(Of Student)
Public Overridable Property Teachers() As ICollection(Of Teacher)
    Get
        Return m_Teachers
    End Get
    Set
        m_Teachers = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private Overridable m_Teachers As ICollection(Of Teacher)
```

End Class